# Shorten S3 signed url

Tags: url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm creating signed URLs and sending them to an external system for later use. Unfortunately there are some length parameters that do not allow extremely long strings to be passed along. Recently, it appears that signed URLs were reformatted and extended which subsequently broke my app.

Is there some method for generating a shorter URL from S3? I would prefer not to rely on a third party URL shortening service for a number of reasons (it's an extra request at URL generation and it adds a point-of-failure).

Comment: I suppose you could create something like `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/short/<random-string>` and have it be a HTML file that does a JS redirect to the signed URL.

Comment: I utilize the signed URL in a simple CURL command `curl -T [file] [url]` so javascript would not be executed.

Comment: You can set up 301s on S3 but that's a bit more complex. Possible, though. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: yeah, 301s is the way to go. It isn't a lot of effort to set up. @ceejayoz

Comment: And, you could make the 301 targets shorter, still, by naming the bucket after a hostname, and pointing the hostname to the bucket's web site endpoint. But there's a fundamental problem with storing signed URLs for very long... in Sig V4 they expire after 7 days max. Sig V2 doesn't have that limit, but rotating your keys will still invalidate all the pre-signed URLs created with the obsoleted key.

Comment: There is no native, straightforward, flip a switch solution... only workarounds and alternatives.  How short do you *need* them to be? And how long are you storing them for later use?

Comment: Looks like my best bet is to build a local "short" url mapper via redis. I only need the URLs to last at max 24 hours (for now) so this is a reasonable solution. The only downside is if my web server goes down, the upload will fail – whereas before it would work regardless of my web server's status since I'm uploading via an external system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can build a **very simple URL Shortener directly within Amazon S3**:

- Turn on **static website hosting**. This will give you a URL to access your bucket, eg: `mybucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`
- Create a **zero-length object** in S3 with a 'short name', eg `pic1.jpg`
- **Add metadata** to the zero-length object:

  - **Key:** `Website Redirect Location`
  - **Value:** The Long URL

Then, when you access the zero-length object (eg `mybucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/pic.jpg`) it will actually redirect to the Long URL stored in the metadata.

Simple, with no database required!

Comment: This is great. Just to share my use-case, I was using curl to upload a file to S3 and had to pull out the redirect before uploading. `curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} SHORT_URL | xargs curl -T file.png` where SHORT_URL is the shortened AWS url.

Comment: this is far from being a short url.. (mybucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/pic.jpg)

Comment: @eiTanLaVi Yes but you can then add the aws s3 route to a forwarding subdomain to shorten the long mybucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com part. That's what I ended up doing. I followed this pattern, and it's working. There's a bit more to some of the bullet points than meets the eye though.

Comment: In this case wouldn't he bucket has to be public?

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of pre-signed url is to provide a [temporary access to download private file from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

**WARNING**: Redirecting to or shortening these urls has security concerns. Final url would need to be difficult to guess/infer, so that it's long and [truly random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)

If your S3 files are meant to be public, you can [mark them as such](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket), and [link to them directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html#virtual-hosted-style-access). Or you can e.g. link [Cloudfront distribution to a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.SimpleDistribution.html), and [assign a custom domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) to that distribution. Or you can use redirect/shorten service.

If your S3 files are meant to be private you can for example send link to a page that requires authentication and has the actual file download button with pre-signed url.